# Como fazer uma consulta de banco com vários filtros

Tags: php, mysqli, formulário, algoritmo-de-busca, filtro

Eu tenho essa lista de filtros 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consigo receber os valores dela tudo normal em um array pelo metodo get, mas estou com duvidas em como fazer para fazer essa busca com diversos filtros, eu realizei um filtro por exemplo buscar por código, ok funcionou, mas como eu intercalo todos esses juntos? não preciso que me diga o código mas qual seria o passo pra eu fazer essa busca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa é uma pergunta recorrente na cabeça dos desenvolvedores, mas as pessoas acham básicas demais para perguntar. Parabéns por perguntar!

Vou dar umas dicas:

## #1 Submeta seu formulário de pesquisa à própria página

```
<form name="busca" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
     <!-- Coloque seus inputs, buttons, selects, etc. aqui dentro -->
</form>
```

## #2 Trate as variáveis logicamente no cabeçalho da página e monte a *query* como resultado desse tratamento lógico e concatenação das *strings* resultantes.

É mais simples do que parece, você precisa apenas saber como a pesquisa deve ser realizada no banco de dados.

Exemplo: Considerando apenas tipo e categoria. Se categoria e tipo estiverem definidos o *query* deve ser `SELECT * FROM minha_tabela WHERE tipo = 'tipo' AND categoria = 'categoria';`, se apenas tipo estiver definido a *query* deve ser `SELECT * FROM minha_tabela WHERE  tipo = 'tipo';` e assim por diante.

```
<?php
// Supondo que o nome do botão clicado seja name="botaoBuscar" no formulário
if(isset($_GET["botaoBuscar"])) {
    // Sempre pegando os valores submetidos por GET por meio do nome dos formulários
    $tipo = $_GET["tipo"];
    $categoria = $_GET["categoria"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM minha_tabela WHERE 1 = 1 "; // Espaço proposital no final

    if(!empty($tipo && isset($tipo) && $tipo !== "")) {
        $query += "AND tipo = " . $tipo;
    }
}

// Conecte-se ao banco de dados e faça sua pesquisa lá.

?>
```

Claro que são exemplos, você pode submeter o formulário para uma página aparte e retornar tudo com JavaScript assincronamente.

São inúmeros métodos diferentes de se fazer a mesma coisa e aí está a beleza da programação pra mim. É um convite para pensarmos e sermos mais criativos no dia a dia como programadores.

Recomendo usar PDO (PHP Data Object).

Comment: Consegui fazer o filtro funcionar, muito obrigado! realmente era mais simples do que imaginava.